# Excel: how to remove multiple file paths from text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2000s of lines in a spread sheet to reference an item image andI need to strip out the file path, but some fields have multiple image references in one cell, so for a complex example:

> /2/0/2099-1.jpg,/2/0/2099-2.jpg,/2/0/2099-3.jpg,/m/a/male_headless_mannequin_-_arms_folded.jpg

need to look like this:

> 2099-1.jpg,2099-2.jpg,2099-3.jpg,male_headless_mannequin_-_arms_folded.jpg

but will have only one image reff, eg:

> /3/1/31-222-007.jpg,

The formula:

```
> =MID(AA2,FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(AA2,"/","*",LEN(AA2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AA2,"/",""))))+1,LEN(AA2))
```

Works great when there is only one jpg, but if there is multiple, i'm stuck.

Thanks

Comment: Are you open to using a VBA function called from the sheet? If not, what about multiple helper columns? Also, your examples have the single image reference ending with a comma but the multiple references do not. Is that consistent throughout the data?

Comment: @EngineerToast i'm open to whatever works ;)  I just need to export out a new csv to helper columns are no problem.  Yes the single images end with a comma, but I don't think it will be an issue for what the csv is being used for, but it also no problem to have the trailing comma removed  (probably better)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With data in `A1`, try:

```
=CONCAT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[substring(., string-length(.) - 3) = '.jpg' or substring(., string-length(.) - 4) = '.jpg,']"))
```

If you run Excel 2019, you'd need to CSE this formula. If one has Excel O365, you don't need to CSE, but there is also a shorter version using `LET()`:

```
=LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(".jpg",X)),X,"")))
```

[image]

---

For those interested, a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) to the Q&A mentioned in my comment below.

Comment: Yet another sample for my collection.

Comment: Thanks @Gary'sStudent. We need to also thank you for your valuable contributions all the time =). Particularly in this case since my solution would require Excel 2019 or O365.

Comment: The one great thing about **VBA** is that it will work on **any** version of Excel *(except maybe Excel4)*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, I'm pretty sure it can be done relatively simple through PowerQuery too, but haven't looked into that.

Comment: 1) I need to learn XPath. 2) Can this be generalized for to work for any file extension?

Comment: @EngineerToast. I wrote an ok Q&A that covers the basics of xpath 1.0 with the `FILTERXML()` function over on StackOverflow. However a generalized xpath leans towards the use of regex which came available with xpath 2.0 and unfortunately isn't supported.

Answer (score 4):

Give this small User Defined Function a try:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function NoPath(sIn As String) As String
    Dim arr, i As Long, v As String, L As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    arr = Split(sIn, ",")
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        v = arr(i)
        L = Len(v)
        For j = L To 1 Step -1
            If Mid(v, j, 1) = "/" Then
                arr(i) = Mid(v, j + 1)
                Exit For
            End If
            Next j
        Next i
        NoPath = Join(arr, ",")
        
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

```
=NoPath(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**